# I need to solve a quadratic

Tags: python, tuples, decimal, quadratic

Write a function solve_quadratic, that returns both solutions of a generic quadratic as a pair (2-tuple) when the coefficients are given as parameters.

It is throwing back decimals and showing an error?

```
import math
 
def solve_quadratic(a, b, c):


    d = int(b*b) - int(4*a*c)

    sol1 = (-b-math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
    sol2 = (-b+math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)

    tup = sol1, sol2;

    print(tup)


    return tup



def main():

    solve_quadratic(1, -3, 2)
    solve_quadratic(1, 2, 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: what's the version of python you are using? No error for me in version 3.7

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: FAIL:
SolveQuadratic: test_random
0.006143383684098502 != 0 within 4 places (0.006143383684098502 difference) : -0.663497 is not a solution for equation 8.794479*x**2 + 6.874397*x + 0.695705 == 0!

Comment: The coefficients are of type ```float``` ?

Comment: What do you have `int(...)`?  Anyway, I don't get an error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the calculation of `d`, it should not truncate the values to `int`s.

```py
def solve_quadratic(a, b, c):
    d = (b*b) - (4*a*c)
    sol1 = (-b-math.sqrt(d))/(2*a) 
    sol2 = (-b+math.sqrt(d))/(2*a)
    tup = sol1, sol2;
    print(tup)
    return tup
```

The reason your code works for (1, -3, 2) and (1, 2, 1) is because `b*b` and `4*a*c` are `int`s for these inputs and there is no truncation/rounding/loss of precision.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula_and_its_derivation